# Spring Integration Channel Statistics Metrics

Tags: statistics, spring-integration, metrics, channel

somehow I dont catch the Spring-Integration Metrics Content. What I want to have is a statistical output about, how many message/second goes through a message channel, what is the min and the max throughput. If I use `newTicketChannel.getSendRate()`, then I become following output:

[image]

What is clear to me is `N`(number of Messages). Mean for me is the number of messages what have been progressed each second (?). But what is totally unclear to me are the values of `min` and `max`. I need something like, min=200, max=380 => means 200 was the lowest rate for the last minute, max 380 the last minute, or something like this.

How is the good practive way? Thanks in advance. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `min` and `max` are since the last `reset()`; if you don't reset they represent the min/max since the app started.

The mean is an exponential moving average over time and a number of messages.

[Documentation here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#mgmt-channel-features).

You would have to periodically `reset()` the `MessageChannelMetrics` to get a new min/max.

Comment: Thanks for you quick replay. When you say `min` and `max` stay same from beginning of starting app, why are the values then different from time to time. And another question for me, how can that be `max` < `mean`?

The Documentation I found already, but somehow it didn`t answer my questions there.

Comment: I did now a scheduler what reset the statistics frequently, that worked for me. Thank you . :-)

test

Comment: But the `getSendRate().getMin()` and `getSendRate().getMax()` output i really dont understand, if mean is e.g. 300, how can be max 0.02 e.g.? I get that values with resetting, too. Till now I get only meanful values with my calculation described in my answer

Comment: I just looked at the code; it's a bit confusing, I agree, but min and max are not rates, they are durations between sends. So `[N=100, min=0.100000, max=0.127000, mean=9.696723, sigma=0.010866]` means the minimum time between sends is 100ms, max is 127ms with a mean (moving) rate of 9.7 messages per second. So the max rate is `1 / min duration` and the min rate is `1 / max duration`.

Comment: But the absolute min/max rate (or duration) is not very interesting; a min/max moving average rate might be more useful. Feel free to open a [new feature JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT), and [contributions are welcome](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.adoc).

Comment: Thank you for your interesting answers. If it is duration, then the value make sense. The confusing thing is, there is also `getSendDuration().getMin()`, this would mean they are identical with `getSendRate().getMin()`. So it is surprising then getting the duration.

Comment: No; `sendDuration()` represents how long a message took to process downstream; i.e the time the `send()` operation took; the `min` here is the minimum time __between__ sends.

Answer (score 0):

In the meanwhile to get the results I want I did following:

Wanted was

1. Messages/Second
2. Max Messages / Second
3. Min Messages / Second

Solutions:

1. `1/newTicketChannel.getSendDuration().getMean() * 1000`
2. `1/newTicketChannel.getSendDuration().getMin() * 1000`
3. `1/newTicketChannel.getSendDuration().getMax() * 1000`

If there are common functionality in spring integration metrics to get same result, please dont hesitate telling me. It would be cool someone provide information about the mean of the values I posted in my question.

Thanks and Cheers :-)