# Spring Integration DSL Gathering Metrics between Flows

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I'm using Spring Integration DSL with ActiveMQ with concurrent consumers and trying to adjust Metrics for Spring IntegrationFlows which interacts with each other using direct channels and routers.

The typical Integration Flow looks like:

```
                                                -> InboundFlow1 -> Transformer|
ActiveMQ Broker ->JMS InboundAdapter -> Router |                             -> OutboundFlow -> JMS OutboundAdapter
                                                -> InboundFlow2 -> Transformer|
```

Each Flow contains inbound JMS Adapter, Router, Filter, Transformer and Outbound JMS Gateway.

Is there any way to gather such metrics from InboundAdapter to OutboundAdapter:

- Amount of messages per second;
- The total amount of messages;
- Min transferring  time through the flow ;
- Max transferring time through the flow;
- The average time of transferring through the Flow;
- Amount of Erroneous messages;
- Duration of handling a message;

I've tried solutions proposed with MessageChannelMetrics:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#mgmt-channel-features
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/monitoring
[Spring Integration Channel Statistics Metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42052881/spring-integration-channel-statistics-metrics?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

But they aren't covered needed functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything except the first and last are present; the first can be derived; the last one would mean capturing it for each message which would be expensive.

However, Spring Integration 5.0.4 now supports [Micrometer](http://micrometer.io/) in addition to those standard metrics.

**EDIT**

Also, you can always add a custom metrics factory if the standard metrics don't do what you need [docs here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/#mgmt-metrics-factory).

Just write your own subclass of `AbstractMessageHandlerMetrics` to capture whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Gary, is it supposed that version of the spring should be update too?

Comment: Yes, Spring Integration 5.0.x requires Spring Framework 5.0.x.

Comment: Unfortunately, migration to the Spring 5 is not as simple, as expected. Can you please add an example, how to calculate   total consumption time for a flow execution?

Comment: I would appreciate for any examples.  I couldn't figure out how to do it the best way using spring-integration examples

Comment: `count * (average) duration` bear in mind that the average duration decays with time and messages so it will only be meaningful if you have a fairly constant rate of message arrival and processing time. You can add a custom metrics factory if the standard metrics don't do what you need [docs here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#mgmt-metrics-factory).

Comment: I just come through. Concerning total amount of incoming messages and average time, i think it is possible to resolve using metrics provided by Channel

Comment: Thanks, Gary, custom metrics factory works well for me.

Comment: @Gary : https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#mgmt-metrics-factory this link gives 404. Could you please provide updated link. Thanks

Comment: I fixed the link but bear in mind the metrics factory is obsolete and deprecated in favor of Micrometer.